# How to identify a legitimate journal from a fake journal?

Tags: journals, conference, publishers, disreputable-publishers

I know using Google Scholar metrics we can get an awareness about legitimate journals, but there are some journals or conferences papers not stated in the Google metrics. Hence I want to know how to identify legitimate journals, conference papers for field of Computer Science from the fake ones.